# Spotify advertisement using bonjour

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I am using Apple bonjour protocol to advertise spotify service. I have to give http port number, IP address of the host and path to zero conf implementation. Can someone please tell me how to mention these arguments in ***DNSServiceRegister()*** function. Please explain with example if possible.

Comment: Repeatedly asking the same question isn't going to get you anywhere. As mentioned in your previous questions: The Spotify Embedded SDK is not a publicly available SDK. Technical support for it is available through your Spotify contact.

Comment: Hi iKenndac, can you please explain me where can i see option to ask for technical support through my contact. I posted in community and didn't get any answer. If i have to mail somebody to get technical support please mention the same.

Comment: Hi iKenndac, and i saw in support section that i have to post either here or IRC to clarify our our doubts. And please tell me the section along with link to ask my doubts. FYI, i am premium user of spotify.

Comment: The only way you (legally) have the Embedded SDK is if you got it directly from a Spotify partner manager. You need to direct your questions to that person — we can only publicly support publicly released libraries.